# 2 stage boot loader with MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, masm, bootloader

here is my code for boot sector and kernel
i am loading my boot sector from usb using int 13 func 42 into 1000:00(h)
and i am jumping to the kernel 
but always nothing happes after loading the kernel...

```
;------------------------------------------------------------
.286                               ; CPU type
;------------------------------------------------------------
.model TINY                        ; memory of model
;---------------------- EXTERNS -----------------------------
extrn               _BootMain:near     ; prototype of C func
;------------------------------------------------------------
;------------------------------------------------------------   
.code   
org             07c00h         ; for BootSector
main:
                jmp short start    ; go to main
                nop

;----------------------- Vairiables -----------------------
        BiosDriveID db  0       

;----------------------- CODE SEGMENT -----------------------
start:  
        cli
        mov     [BiosDriveID],dl
        mov     ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
        mov     ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
        mov     es,ax               ; Make ES correct
        mov     ss,ax               ; Make SS correct        
        mov     bp,7c00h
        mov     sp,7c00h            ; Setup a stack
        sti

        ;call           _BootMain



        mov     si, OFFSET msgLoading
        call    DisplayMessage


     ;*************************************************************************
     ; Setup DISK ADDRESS PACKET
     ;*************************************************************************

        mov     si, OFFSET msgDAPACK
        call    DisplayMessage
        jmp     strtRead

        DAPACK:
                db      010h         ; Packet Size
                db      0            ; Always 0
        blkcnt: 
                dw      1            ; Sectors Count    
        db_add:
                dw      01000h       ; Transfer Segment
                dw      0h           ; Transfer Offset
        d_lba:
                dd      1            ; Starting LBA (0 - n)
                dd      0            ; Bios 48 bit LBA


     ;*************************************************************************
     ; Start Reading Sectors using INT13 Func 42     
     ;*************************************************************************
strtRead:
        mov     si, OFFSET msgSectors
        call    DisplayMessage

        mov     si, OFFSET DAPACK
        mov     ah,042h             
        mov     dl,[BiosDriveID]
        int     013h    
        jc      readError
        jmp     readOK

     ;*************************************************************************
     ; Sectors Reading Error
     ;*************************************************************************
readError:
        mov     si,OFFSET msgFailure
        call    DisplayMessage
        hlt


     ;*************************************************************************
     ; Sectors Reading OK
     ;*************************************************************************
readOK:
        mov     si, OFFSET msgReadOK
        call    DisplayMessage

        mov     ax,01000h
        mov     ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
        mov     es,ax               ; Make ES correct
        mov     ss,ax               ; Make SS correct 

        db      09Ah
        dw      0000h
        dw      1000h

        ;mov        si, OFFSET msgLoading
        ;call   DisplayMessage


        ;call   farKernel
        ;push   1000h
        ;push   0000h
        ;retf
        hlt



        ret




     ;*************************************************************************
     ; PROCEDURE DisplayMessage
     ; display ASCIIZ string at ds:si via BIOS
     ;*************************************************************************
     DisplayMessage     proc    near
          lodsb                                       ; load next character
          or      al, al                              ; test for NUL character
          jz      DONE
          mov     ah, 00Eh                            ; BIOS teletype
          mov     bh, 000h                            ; display page 0
          mov     bl, 007h                            ; text attribute
          int     010h                                ; invoke BIOS
          jmp     DisplayMessage
     DONE:
          ret
     DisplayMessage     endp
     ;*************************************************************************


;*******************************************************************************
;messages that needs to be shown

     msgLoading:
                db 00Dh, 00Ah, "******************************************"
                db 00Dh, 00Ah, "* AFME Operating System Version 1.00...  *"             
                db 00Dh, 00Ah, "******************************************", 00Dh, 00Ah,000h

     msgDAPACK   db 00Dh, 00Ah, "Setup Disk Addressing Packet...", 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h
     msgSectors  db 00Dh, 00Ah, "Start Loading Sectors...", 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h

     msgFailure  db 00Dh, 00Ah, "Kernel loading failed...", 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h

     msgReadOK   db 00Dh, 00Ah, "Kernel loading succeded...", 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h 

     msgCRLF     db 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h



     db 506-($-start) dup (0)
     dw 0AA55h
     ;************************************************************************* 

KERNEL:



     END main                ; End of program
```

and kernel

```
;------------------------------------------------------------
.286                               ; CPU type
;------------------------------------------------------------
.model TINY                        ; memory of model
;---------------------- EXTERNS -----------------------------
;extrn              _BootMain:near     ; prototype of C func
;------------------------------------------------------------
;------------------------------------------------------------   
.code   
org             0h         ; for Kernel
main:
;----------------------- CODE SEGMENT -----------------------
start:  

        mov     ah,9
        mov     al,64
        mov     bh, 0                            ; display page 0
        mov     bl,4
        mov     cx,1
        int     010h
        hlt
        mov     si, OFFSET msgHello
        call    DisplayMessage

        hlt


     ;*************************************************************************
     ; PROCEDURE DisplayMessage
     ; display ASCIIZ string at ds:si via BIOS
     ;*************************************************************************
     DisplayMessage     proc    near
          lodsb                                       ; load next character
          or      al, al                              ; test for NUL character
          jz      DONE
          mov     ah, 00Eh                            ; BIOS teletype
          mov     bh, 000h                            ; display page 0
          mov     bl, 007h                            ; text attribute
          int     010h                                ; invoke BIOS
          jmp     DisplayMessage
     DONE:
          ret
     DisplayMessage     endp
     ;*************************************************************************


;*******************************************************************************
;messages that needs to be shown




     msgHello  db 00Dh, 00Ah, "Helloo From the kernel...", 00Dh, 00Ah, 000h

     END main                ; End of program
```

can anybody help?

Comment: Please give the corresponding commands for compiling. Also how do you test your booloader: in a virtual machine like VirtualBox / QEmu / ... ? Give more details.

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger and verify your code is actually loaded and then single step it.

Comment: i am using virtualbox with physical usb

Comment: compile with ML.EXE /AT /c and link with LINK.EXE /T /NOD

Comment: also i used emu8086 to simulate the whole idea by copying the kernel into the targeted segment offset and run the loader and it worked perfectly

Comment: also i have updated to use 0000h:07e00h to load the kernel and also failed

Comment: Might want to set up `ds`  before you save bootdrive in `dl`.

Comment: i get assured that the kernel is being loaded into the memory location, i have put a zero terminated string in the kernel sector, and i mov si,7e00h and then call DispalyMessage and it is displayed correctly, this means the kernel is loading correctly.

Comment: Eyeballing the code, I'm not sure what you are trying to do in `readOK`. After `mov     ss,ax ` followed by data `db`, `dw`, `dw`. I didn't check to see if that converts to legal instructions. So what is that about? Even more concerning is that before the `ret` you issue a `hlt`? How does it return from readOK?

Comment: @MichaelPetch that's a far call to `1000:0000`. Not sure why he handcoded it. The `hlt` is there in case the kernel ever returns, which it is not expected to do.

Comment: Yeah as I said I didn't actually look it up to see if it was legal instructions. Thanks,. If it is  a far call then nothing wrong except why he didn't just use the assembly instructions unless of course masm doesn't have anything that maps to it.

Comment: Normally I just far `jmp` out of the boot sector routine expecting to never return.

Comment: Had a few minutes to look a bit closer. I notice that for the read you have the packet defined with `dw 01000h` followed by `dw 0h`. The offset should be first and segment should come second because it is little endian. So I think it might be better to define it this way: `dw 0h` followed by `dw 01000h` . If it is backwards you won't be reading it to memory that you intend to far call to.

Comment: Yep Michael.... that it ,, i forgot that little endian...   thanks it is working fine now...

Comment: @MichaelPetch: it seems that you should wrap your last comment into an answer, so it would be easier to find the answer of the question, and so we could upvote your for the fixing the problem :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a couple of issues with your code. The first is a minor one. Your boot loader starts with:

```
start:  
        cli
        mov     [BiosDriveID],dl
        mov     ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
        mov     ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
```

You `mov` the boot drive letter to `BiosDriveID`. however you do it before setting up `DS`. When you write `mov [BiosDriveID],dl`, the `DS` segment is assumed but you haven't actually set it. You can't rely on the BIOS jumping to your boot sector with DS already being valid. You should make sure you setup `DS` first:

```
start:  
        cli
        mov     ax,cs               ; Setup segment registers
        mov     ds,ax               ; Make DS correct
        .
        .
        mov     [BiosDriveID],dl    ; DS is properly set.
```

The primary bug that prevents launching your kernel is that the disk read you have done uses this packet:

```
    DAPACK:
            db      010h         ; Packet Size
            db      0            ; Always 0
    blkcnt: 
            dw      1            ; Sectors Count    
    db_add:
            dw      01000h       ; Transfer Segment
            dw      0h           ; Transfer Offset
    d_lba:
            dd      1            ; Starting LBA (0 - n)
            dd      0            ; Bios 48 bit LBA
```

In particular `db_add` is suppose hold *segment:offset* . You have done that however you haven't placed them in the correct order. Intel x86 is little endian so if you break up *segment:offset* into two separate *WORDS* you have to account for endianness and place *offset* before *segment* . The fix is simple - swap *segment* and *offset* in your structure. It would read:

```
    DAPACK:
            db      010h         ; Packet Size
            db      0            ; Always 0
    blkcnt: 
            dw      1            ; Sectors Count    
    db_add:
            dw      0h           ; Transfer Offset   \ Reversed to conform
            dw      01000h       ; Transfer Segment  / to little Endian
    d_lba:
            dd      1            ; Starting LBA (0 - n)
            dd      0            ; Bios 48 bit LBA
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Michael , i forgot the little endian , so after replacing the offset and segment in DAPACK it is working properly .
thanks for all.